# como mostrar la fecha donde el valor de esta es null en mysql

Tags: mysql

Buenos días chicos quisiera que por favor me ayuden. Estoy haciendo un registro de asistencia y en la consulta que realizo sale lo que quiero pero en algunos casos la fecha me sale como nulo,  lo que quiero es que me muestre la fecha que la persona no ha marcado su asistencia no se si  me pueden ayudar no se como solucionar esto.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT  tb_horarios.codigopersonal, tb_personal_org.nombres, tb_registroasistencia.fecha, 
        tb_horarios.j_codigo, tb_horarios.dia, tb_horarios.hora_entrada, tb_horarios.hora_salida, 
        tb_registroasistencia.hora_entra, tb_registroasistencia.hora_sale, 
        tb_horarios.numero_horas, 
        (SEC_TO_TIME((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, tb_horarios.hora_entrada, tb_registroasistencia.hora_entra))*60)) AS ATRASOS
from  tb_horarios 
LEFT JOIN tb_registroasistencia ON (tb_horarios.codigopersonal = tb_registroasistencia.psn_codigo) 
          and (tb_horarios.j_codigo = tb_registroasistencia.jnd_codigo) 
          AND (tb_horarios.dia= tb_registroasistencia.dia)
LEFT JOIN tb_personal_org ON tb_horarios.codigopersonal = tb_personal_org.codigo
where  tb_horarios.prd_codigo=1  
ORDER BY `tb_personal_org`.`nombres`  ASC
```

Comment: Mira [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: Bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Al usar `LEFT JOIN`, te pondrá el valor `NULL` en aquellas columnas donde no haya coincidencias. Puedes usar en su lugar `INNER JOIN`, en cuyo caso te traerá solamente los registros coincidentes. Si así no te da los resultados esperados, deberás revisar tu consulta y quizá hasta tus datos. Si no encuentras respuesta, entonces puedes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/131434/edit), dando más detalles de lo que quieres hacer e indicando cómo están formadas las tablas que intervienen en este caso y cómo se relacionan entre ellas.

Comment: Podrías enseñarnos una muestra de los datos?